# Get the first 6 or 7 (conditional) characters of an object

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Im trying to get the first 6 or 7 character of an object. This object have the name of Panel object and, I want to pass this characters to another variable to work whit them.

**This is my code.**

```
Dim p1Name
Dim paParent
Dim clickedPanel

Private Sub ToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ToolStripMenuItem.Click

    clickedPanel = DirectCast(DirectCast(DirectCast(sender, ToolStripMenuItem).Owner, ContextMenuStrip).SourceControl, Panel)
    p1Name = clickedPanel.Name

    If Len(p1Name) = 7 Then
        paParent = clickedPanel.name
    Else
        paParent = clickedPanel.name.Substring(0, 7)
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub SwPan()

    Dim varE As String = paParent
    Dim PanelParent As Panel = paParent

        Dim p3 = DirectCast(PanelParent.Controls.Find(p1Name, True).FirstOrDefault(), Panel)
        If p3 Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentException("index1")
end sub
```

When I try to run, send the next error message.

```
index and length must refer to a location within the string parameter name length vb.net
```

Please, could you help me to fix or guide me?

Thank you in advance.

**Update I do the next.**

This is to get (cut)

```
Private Sub ToolStripMenuItem3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ToolStripMenuItem3.Click

    clickedPanel = DirectCast(DirectCast(DirectCast(sender, ToolStripMenuItem).Owner, ContextMenuStrip).SourceControl, Panel)

p1Name = clickedPanel.Name

    paParent = clickedPanel.parent

End Sub
```

**this is to do (paste)**

```
Private Sub ToolStripMenuItem4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ToolStripMenuItem4.Click
    clickedPanel = DirectCast(DirectCast(DirectCast(sender, ToolStripMenuItem).Owner, ContextMenuStrip).SourceControl, Panel)

    p2Name = clickedPanel.Name

    pbParent = clickedPanel.parent

    Call Swap()

End Sub
```

**This is to swap panels**

```
Private Sub Swap()

        '' build the panel names
        Dim varA As String = p1Name.ToString
        Dim varC As String = p2Name.ToString

        Dim PanelParent As Panel = paParent
        Dim PanelParent_b As Panel = pbParent

        Dim p3 = DirectCast(PanelParent.Controls.Find(p1Name, True).FirstOrDefault(), Panel)
        If p3 Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentException("index1")

        Dim p4 = DirectCast(PanelParent_b.Controls.Find(p2Name, True).FirstOrDefault(), Panel)
        If p4 Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentException("index2")

        Dim positionA As Integer = Panel1.AutoScrollPosition.X

        Panel1.AutoScroll = False

        Dim temp = p4.Location
        p4.Location = p3.Location
        p3.Location = temp

        Panel1.AutoScroll = True

        Panel1.AutoScrollPosition = New Point(positionA, Panel1.VerticalScroll.Maximum)

    End Sub
```

Comment: Your conditional statement considers when the length of p1Name is 7 it returns the name of the panel. If it's greater than 7 calling Substring(0, 7) will successfully return the substring. If its less than 7 calling Substring(0, 7) will cause the error message you described. "Try Len(p1Name) <= 7 Then" You can also use p1Name instead of reading from clickedPanel.Name multiple times.

Comment: Why are you using strings here? `clickedPanel` is a Control. Its parent container is `clickedPanel.Parent`. Set `Option Strict On`.

Comment: @Jimi thank you for your answer and your time. I´m trying to get the father of a panel that is inside another panel, this with the later objective of being able to move that panel between panels. What I know is that I have to know who I move and where I move it, in this case every panel that is inside, they have in their name the name of the parent panel, that's why what I try is to get the name and then cut to then put it to another panel type variable to work it.

Comment: @jazakari, thank your for your answer, but the issue is not in the conditional, is in this line `paParent = clickedPanel.name.Substring(0, 7)`

Comment: You don't need to know the whole hierarchy of ancestors. You can simply set the `Parent` property to another reference, the reference of the new `Parent` container (another Panel or ~anything else).

Comment: @Jimi its correct if I use this? `paParent = clickedPanel.parent`, because my issue in this part is `$exception {"Public member 'FirstOrDefault' on type 'Control()' not found."}`

Comment: You mean `clickedPanel.Parent = [Another Control Reference]` (e.g., `clickedPanel.Parent = panel2`).

Comment: Hi @Jimi, I do the reference, the panels can move in the same Panel, but when I try to move to another Panel, no move. My logic is wrong right? (please review the update).

Comment: @LARC Your conditional is trying to take 7 characters from the start of `p1Name` when the length is not equal to 7. The problem is when there are less than 7 characters this causes an exception.You only need to call `Substring(0,7)` when `p1Name` has a length greater than 7 characters.

Comment: Don't use strings **anywhere**. You have your Control, the one you want to swap with another: `clickedPanel`. Pass this instance to the `Swap()` method (don't use Fields to reference these controls). The container of `clickedPanel` is `clickedPanel.Parent`. You want to swap this Control with another (it's undetermined how you selected this other control). Now `originalParent = clickedPanel.Parent`, `clickedPanel.Parent = theOtherControl.Parent`, `theOtherControl.Parent = originalParent`.

Comment: @jazakari, I understand, the issue in that line is for the length in the string and the length in the conditional, fixed that line, thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: I now recall I've already suggested you to use a TablelayoutPanel to achieve this *effect*, with a [result like this](https://imgur.com/vOIuEAQ) (or more complex: you could select one control and swap with another on the second click). It would simplify everything. You should explore the TLP properties and methods, to see how simple it is to swap child controls, simply using their Cell position.

Comment: @Jimi, yes, but in this case, I already have this process very advanced, and it would take me a long time to return. Believe me, I saw the option you showed me, and I find it quite good, but for haste and status, I can't go back to doing it again. See the tablelayout I will review it, but a little later, since it makes me a good option too.

Answer (score 0):

Good day.

Sorry for this delay, but I found the solution to this problem.

Attach the updated code.

Thank you all for the effort and time.

Regards

```
Private Sub Swap()

        Dim PanelParent As Panel = paParent
        Dim PanelParent_b As Panel = pbParent

        Dim p3 = DirectCast(PanelParent.Controls.Find(p1Name, True).FirstOrDefault(), Panel)
        If p3 Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentException("index1")

        Dim p4 = DirectCast(PanelParent_b.Controls.Find(p2Name, True).FirstOrDefault(), Panel)
        If p4 Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentException("index2")

        Dim positionA As Integer = Panel1.AutoScrollPosition.X

        Panel1.AutoScroll = False

        Dim temp = p4.Location
        Dim temp_b = p3.Location

        With p3
            .Parent = PanelParent_b
            .Location = temp
        End With

        With p4
            .Parent = PanelParent
            .Location = temp_b
        End With

        Panel1.AutoScroll = True

        Panel1.AutoScrollPosition = New Point(positionA, Panel1.VerticalScroll.Maximum)

    End Sub
```